# Implement url without end slash

Tags: java, spring-webflux, spring-rest

I use this Java client to make POST requests:

Implementation

```
public Mono<PaymentResponse> executeAndReceive(String transaction) {
        Mono<String> transactionMono = Mono.just(transaction);
        return client.post().uri(gatewayUrl + "{token}", token)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Response.class);
    }
```

I use this code to call the client:

```
String GATEWAY_PROCESSING_URL  = http://www.some_host:8080/rest_api/v1/

String token = 342552334

RestClient client = RestClientBuilder.builder()
                    .gatewayUrl(GATEWAY_PROCESSING_URL)
                    .token(token)
                    .usernamePassword(user_name, password)
                    .build();
```

But sometimes I forgot to set `/` at the end of the URL.
Is there some way to detect this and set it automatically if it's missing?

Comment: Can you please describe how you forget to add `/` at the end of url? I can see you are declaring `GATEWAY_PROCESSING_URL` at the start. Also given the variable's use and already in all caps letters, you should consider making it final.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is a safety check whether the url ends with a '/' just use the example below.

```
String url = ... some url ...
if (url.endsWith("/") == false) {
    url += "/";
}
```